# Proving decidability of subset in Agda

Tags: subset, agda, decidable

Suppose I have this definition of Subset in Agda

```
Subset : ∀ {α} → Set α → {ℓ : Level} → Set (α ⊔ suc ℓ)
Subset A {ℓ} = A → Set ℓ
```

and I have a set

```
data Q : Set where
 a : Q
 b : Q
```

Is it possible to prove that all subset of q is decidable and why?

```
Qs? : (qs : Subset Q {zero}) → Decidable qs
```

Decidable is defined here:

```
-- Membership
infix 10 _∈_
_∈_ : ∀ {α ℓ}{A : Set α} → A → Subset A → Set ℓ
a ∈ p = p a

-- Decidable
Decidable : ∀ {α ℓ}{A : Set α} → Subset A {ℓ} → Set (α ⊔ ℓ)
Decidable as = ∀ a → Dec (a ∈ as)
```

Comment: This subset definition doesn't allow that. You can just have `const t : Subset Q` for some `t` that is not decidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for that definition of Subset, since decidability would require to check whether "p a" is inhabited or not, i.e. excluded middle.

Decidable subsets would exactly be maps into Bool:

```
Subset : ∀ {α} (A : Set α) -> Set
Subset A = A → Bool 

_∈_ : ∀ {α}{A : Set α} → A → Subset A → Set
a ∈ p = T (p a)
```

But if you want more flexibility on the shape of the membership proofs you could use your definition of Subset and carry around a proof that it is Decidable.